# Can xpath be used in coded ui tests to locate a web element?

Tags: xpath, coded-ui-tests

I am currently working on a test automation project in which the IDs of certain controls(web elements) changes with the test environment. Moreover, these IDs are auto generated and thus i can't apply a PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains for the search properties of the control.

So my ask: Is there any way to locate the controls via XPath in coded ui tests?

Comment: You can't use IDs in this situation, but you can search those elements using other things like: tag name, class name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to generate an XPath that can find the controls, then you should be able to create a coded ui test that finds them.  What in the XPath are you using that is stable?  Those same things can be used in CodedUI.  Can you please post your sample XPath and HTML that it finds?